# Why doesn't my run() method correctly call from my Actionlistener

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

i´m working on a Snake implementation and am mostly done. My only problem is, that,when my `JMenuItem` for starting a new game is clicked the game freezes. Here´s the relevant code:

```
             this.newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                 {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                 neuesSpiel();
             }

                 });





             public void neuesSpiel()
             {     //The old snake game is finished and the playing field is reseted
                  if(snake!=null)
                  {
                      snake.beendeSpiel();

                      for(int i=0; i<20;i++)
                      {
                           for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
                           {    
                            spielfeld[i][j] = false;
                            }
                      }

                  }//the new snake game is created below
                  snake = new Snake(null,null, 10,5, this);     
                  Snake snake2 = new Snake(snake,null,11,5,this);
                  snake.hintermann = snake2;
                  snake2.hintermann = new Snake(snake2,null,12,5,this);

                  snake.run();
               }
```

In the class Snake:

```
public void run()
{
Game.zf.requestFocus();

while(spiellauf){
try
{
    Thread.sleep( 120 );
} 
catch ( InterruptedException e ) { }
if(spiellauf)
bewege(); //the Snake Block is moved
}
```

I´m pretty sure, that the `run()` method is the problem, because if i don´t call the method, the game doesnt freeze. Furthermore the method `neuesSpiel()` should be ok too, because when I call it in the constructor it works as intended.
I don´t know how else i can make my function wait for 120ms besides using threads. Is there an alternative? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> I don´t know how else i can make my function wait for 120ms besides using threads.

You are not using threads. You are executing your `run` method in the current thread.

If you wish to run it in a new thread, you need something like :

```
new Thread(snake).start();
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. But still, if I run a new thread the game freezes. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Monocle for the same exact reason -- you're blocking the Swing event thread, likely in code you're not showing us. solution: don't do this, don't block the EDT. Google and read "Concurrency and Swing". Study everything in it.